# Reduce time complexity of program

Tags: python-3.x, time-complexity

I have written a function to remove items specified in a given list.

```
def remove_given_elements(arr1) :
    b = []
    x = int(input("Enter the number of items to be removed :"))
    for i in range(x) :
        y = int(input("Enter the position to be removed :"))
        b.append(y)

    arr3 = []
    pos = 0

    for i in range(len(arr1)) :
        arr3.append(arr1[i])
        for j in range(len(b)):
            if pos == b[j]:
                arr3.pop(b[j])
                arr3.append(None)
        pos += 1

    arr4 = []

    for i in arr3:
        if i != None :
            arr4.append(i)

    return arr4

a = [100,200,323,434,512,656]
print("After removing elements",remove_given_elements(a))
```

Output :

```
Enter the number of items to be removed :3
Enter the position to be removed :1
Enter the position to be removed :3
Enter the position to be removed :4
After removing elements [100, 323, 656]
```

As, i am new to programming. I really don't know any methods to decrease my worst case time complexity. Any kind of help is appreciated or please guide me to use proper methods which decreases time complexity.

Comment: You need to specify the amounts of items to be removed?

Comment: @Eduardo Yes, as i want to remove multiple items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ask before for the positions and store them in a tuple. Then apply the function.

```
def remove(_list, pos):
    return [v for i, v in enumerate(_list) if i not in pos]

positions = (1, 2, 3)
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
result = remove(l, positions)
print(result)
```

The function return a [List Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)